# Round a number at 0.5

Tags: php

I try to round a number at 0.5

This is my examples :

```
5.1 > 5
2.4 > 2.5
1 > 1
6.8 > 7
6.2 > 6.5
```

I try with :

```
<?php
round((4.4 * 2) / 2)
?>
```

But :

```
5.4 > 5
4.7 > 5
```

instead of

```
5.4 > 5.5
4.7 > 4.5
```

Any idea ?

Comment: with a own function or on-board functions?

Answer (score 6):

Why not just double the value, round on a full number and then devide by 2:

```
$res = round($value*2) / 2
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: no, it aint. there is a difference in when the rounding happens. you round at the end. therefore, you will never get anything other than an integer. I round first, get an integer and then divide by two. Which produces the aspired result.

Answer (score 2):

```
round(4.4*2)/2;
```

You are just mixing up the order.

You want to round up the number which is original number multiplied by 2 and after that round - you want to divide it by 2.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
Echo round(4.4 / 0.5)*.5;
```

You should think like this:
You want the number to be divided by the fraction you want. (0.5).
Then you round that number which means you remove the fraction and then multiply with the fraction you want again to get back to the number you had but rounded.

Just look at the calculation and let it sink in and you will understand it.

If you want to always round down, use floor instead of round.
If you want to round up, use ceil instead of round.

As an example

```
Echo round(12 / 5)*5;
```

Will round to closest 5.

Comment: of course *2 is the same as /.5 but I think dividing by 1/2 makes code slightly less readable.

Comment: Yes but in contrast. Your calculation only (as far as my brain can think right now) works for this scenario. Let's say you want to round on 5 instead https://3v4l.org/4iYbQ . Yes my code may be less readable, BUT it works with any calculation. If you want to round on closest 100 value just replace `0.5` with `100`. How is that for readability? @matiit

Comment: I am not saying that your example is not correct or even more correct for a broader use. I am only saying that in my opinion for this particular problem - your code (without comments at least) is less readable, which means that it will take a little bit longer to understand what is the purpose of that code in the given context.

I hope I explained myself properly.

Comment: @matiit *without comments*? Are you joking???! My whole answer is the comments. In my opinion learning one method that works for all cases, even if (some) find it less readable is better than a "one time solution". YMMV

Comment: By comments, I meant comments which you would put along the code in the actual real-life code base.
And I would recommend you some meditation so you are less stressed. The amount of "?" and "!" you type indicates you are pretty emotional about this. 

Less stress - better quality of life :)

No offence

Comment: @matiit and how many comments do you have inline your code? http://www.gatefans.net/gforums/attachments/reverse-1275389857_naked-gun-facepalm-gif.26605/ some people.... Gosh....